# Reading Linked Text File From Resources with StreamReader

Tags: c#, resources

I have seen many examples that show StreamReader taking the arugment "Properties.Resources.someTextFile, and apparently they work great. However, in .net 4.5 I still get:

[image: Error Message]

```
//while not end of file, read lines of file and split into array
string myFile = Properties.Resources.data;

string line;

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myFile);

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{

    string[] array = line.Split('#');

    string tickerSymbol = array[0];

    string regPattern = array[1];
```

....

[image: Resources]

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: See if this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3314213/49251 helps.

Answer (score 2):

By accessing the data text file resource through Properties.Resources the resulting variable myFile should contain the string contents of the file.

```
string myFile = Properties.Resources.data;

var lines = myFile.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach(var line in lines)
{
     // Process each line...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @TMS. The code you presented accesses the file. Still, I do not understand why the argument "myFile" throws an exception in StreamReader.

Comment: The StreamReader constructor accepts either a path to a file (c:\directory\filename.ext) or an existing stream. Since Properties.Resources.data returns the contents of the file as a string the reader doesn't know what to do with it.